# bandwidth of digital control design in conventional dc-dc converter

Tags: analog, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, bandwidth, sampling

I designed conventional single inductor two output dc-dc boost converter in psim.  This means inductor energy is stored and thrown to 1 output at one cycle and charged and discharged to the 2nd output at next cycle.  The two outputs are sensed by using voltage dividers and time multiplexed using analog mux at the speed of half of the switching freq to be processed in the digital control stage. My digital stage is very simple pid with z transfer func. After that pwm controls the switches on/off time. 
 The design works well.

vin 2V
 vo1 4V
 vo2 6V
 fs =1M
 L=4uH
 c=50uF
 etc...

so my question is in above scenario, does the bandwidth in the control should be greater than switching frequency or less than switching frequency?
 thanks
[image]

Comment: Could you add scheme?

Comment: yes , I added the shematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reasonable guarantee of stability your process/measurement/control bandwidth should be significantly greater than the bandwidth of the analogue LC filter that smoothes the output.

It's not a 100% guarantee but a reasonable guarantee of stability.

---

Reason: -

If you are switching at 1 MHz then your LC filter (yes you must have an output capacitor although not shown in your circuit) MUST be significantly more "sluggish" than the switching frequency to obtain adequately small ripple voltage on the output. This of course is easy to achieve with pretty small components so there's no excuse for bad selection.

Sampling/controlling at a higher speed can achieve not much else other than a slight improvement in accuracy due to the ability to numerically average the ripple voltage but, as I said earlier, it's sensible to make the natural ripple voltage low by use of an appropriately scaled LC filter.

From the L and C values you quote, the analogue cut-off frequency is about 11 kHz. If you are alternately switching at 500 kHz then the size of the ripple voltage will be determined by a 40 dB / decade roll-off: -

[image]

Resonance is about 11 kHz and, at 1 MHz, the attenuation of the switching waveform will be about 80 dB and, at 500 kHz will be about 78 dB or 8000:1. So, if Vin is 2V, the switching waveform will be 2V p-p and, with a bit of hand-waving the ripple will be about 8000 times lower i.e. sub milli-volts.

In other words you have chosen an L and a C combination that are more than adequate for this design. Your control loop could probably work at a speed of 100 kHz without much problem.

Comment: 1- you mean the time-multiplexing will not affect if the analog mux runs at 2x(LC filter) 2- So, if I change the input parameters example.. to Vin =1.8, fs =5MHz, L=600nH, c=2uF , and outputs Vo1 =2V , Vo2 =2.2V, analog mux runs at 5Mhz , then I could see that my cut-off is 145.2kHz. so in this case how much will be bandwidth of control design

Comment: No, the multiplexer is "the new switching frequency" and this (500 kHz) MUST be significantly higher that the LC 3 dB cut-off (11 kHz) which it is. Please don't start changing scenarios; it's Sunday and I probably have better things to do. Your question has been answered and realistically I don't have time to go through a swathe of what ifs. Just try it. 5 MHz / 142 kHz is closer than 500 kHz / 11 kHz so bear this in mind but it should still be OK.

Comment: @Andy aka: how do you get 2V p-p and in this case, where is LC filter?  L and C are separated by the switches and it is not LC filter any more?

Comment: @anhnha 2 volts was mentioned in the question and I mentioned 2 volts p-p but, the level is not important, only the attenuation. Whatever topology is used and no matter what separates the L and C, they still form a 2nd order low pass filter.

Comment: In question,  Vin is a constant 2V DC  but you said 2V p-p so I was a bit confused. For the LC filter,  is there a formal proof for that?  I only see LC filter in buck converter not boost converter.

Comment: @Andyaka: in question, Vin is a constant 2V DC but you said 2V p-p so I was a bit confused. For the LC filter, is there a formal proof for that? I only see LC filter in buck converter not boost converter.

Comment: Formal proof of what?

Comment: @Andyaka: you said "Whatever topology is used and no matter what separates the L and C, they still form a 2nd order low pass filter". I am confused if in case L and C are separated as in boost converter, is the corner frequency of that low pass filter still 1/sqrt(LC) as you used above or it will modify somehow.

Comment: @anhnha there are two half cycles of operation in a switching converter and for buck converters both phases (storing energy and release of energy) influence the output voltage a little bit on a cycle by cycle basis. As for a boost circuit only the second part of the cycle directly influences the output capacitor so it is slightly different but, when the 2nd half of the cycle happens, you can say the inductor is connected to the capacitor and it will still form a resonant low pass filter....

Comment: ... you could also argue that in a simple buck converter, the 2nd part of the cycle is connecting the inductor and capacitor via a flyback diode (just as a booster) so there isn't much difference. Maybe it would help if you used LTSpice to sim it.

Answer (score 0):

Your digital (sampling) bandwidth should be much faster than your analog control (output switching). And by "much faster" I mean 5-10x faster. I'd get a dual channel 5 megasamples per second ADC and use a very fast SPI bus for a micro-controller to read the data and then adjust the switching outputs as required.

That is, of course, assuming you have a microcontroller running this control loop.

Comment: yes thank you . but I am confused why in the single output loop .. bandwidth =crossover freq is always less than fs switching freq.
is it because of two channels multiplexing

Comment: The control loop can be as fast as you want but it needn't be more than 5 to 10 times faster than the LC response in all reasonable designs. You seem to be implying that it needs to be faster than the switching frequency and this is total overkill.

Comment: @Andyaka you are right, the system's response time is the key part.. not really the switching frequency.